# linux how to find specific files in specific folders

Tags: linux, find

This is my folder structure:

/site1/myFolder/otherFolder1/a.gif

/site1/myFolder/otherFolder1/b.png

/site1/myFolder/otherFolder1/c.php

...

/site2/myFolder/otherFolder2/d.gif

/site2/myFolder/otherFolder2/e.png

/site2/myFolder/otherFolder2/f.php

...

/site3/myFolder/otherFolder3/g.gif

/site3/myFolder/otherFolder3/h.png

/site3/myFolder/otherFolder3/i.php

...

Got this far:

```
find /var/www/html -type d -name myFolder -exec find {} -name "*.php"  \;

for i in `find /var/www/html -type d -name myFolder -exec find {} -name "*.php"  \;`
  do
    some_house_keeping_here
  done
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
find /var/www/html -type d -name myFolder -exec find {} -name "*.php" -exec do_some_housekeeping {} \; \;
```

Comment: why it closed and not moved to SuperUser? we need answers

Comment: the answer is here http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/find-how-search-multiple-folders-directories-unix

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `-path` option instead of `-name`. It would match the entire absolute path with the regex.

```
find /var/www/html -path "*/myFolder/*.php" -exec do_some_housekeeping {} \;
```

Comment: This works well for the moment, but I do think the find within a find could be useful in many other situations. Any help on that front will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a handy answer. Just pointing out that in this case, `"*/myFolder/*.php"` is not a regex.  It's a filename pattern, and it's probably applied with file globbing rules.  A regex is a different pattern language.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `-path` flag that would probably help a lot.

```
find /var/www/html -path "myFolder/otherFolder?" -name "*.php" -exec do_some_housekeeping {} \;
```